# Regulating negative voltage with a positive LDO

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, negative

I have Traco TEN 5-1221 to generate positive and negative 5 volts. I need to further lower the voltage to 1.5V. I decided to use a BA15JC5T for positive 1.5 volts.

Is there a way to use it for negative 1.5V as well or do I need an LDO for negative voltage?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to use it for negative 1.5V as well or do I need ldo
> for negative voltage.*

No, you need to have a negative voltage regulator for the negative 1.5 volts. However, if the current draw is only a few mA, you might be able to get-away with an inverting op-amp.